# Postman test API y JWT

Tags: .net, jwt, postman

Estoy tratando de realizar una prueba con Postman sobre una API que requiere un JWT, este token lo consigo llamando a una URL diferente al de la API que luego debo colocar como un en string de datos en el header de la URL de la API.

Voy a tratar de ejenplicar de manera más sencilla el proceso

Tengo URL_a y URL_b

URL_a se encarga de la autentificación y de generar el token.
URL_b es la que contiene la API

Para poder hacer el test del API debo llamar a URL_a y esta me generará un JWT que lo añadiré como header a la llamada de la URL_b.

El problema es que no me queda claro que Postman pueda llamar a la URL_a para que el resultado lo añada en la URL_b, eso es lo que no se hacer :(

Gracias,

Comment: Mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Comment: Hola, te aconsejo leas con detenimiento este artículo [JSON Web Token - Seguridad en servicios Web API 2 de ASP.NET](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/6/17/json-web-token-seguridad-en-servicios-web-api-2-de-aspnet). Si tu Web API es de .NET Core este [JSON Web Token - Seguridad en servicios Web API de .NET Core](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/5/20/json-web-token-seguridad-en-servicios-web-api-de-net-core)

Comment: Si te refieres hacer peticiones con postman y en la petición enviar un token, si se puede.

Comment: Que has intentado en postman?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un pre-request script, que cómo su nombre lo indica, es un script que se ejecuta antes de lanzar tu petición, en este script puedes hacer la petición a tu servidor de autenticación para que te de un token y pasarselo al encabezado correspondiente de tu petición a URL_b.

Aquí el enlace a la documentación, [Pre-request scripts.](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/pre-request-scripts/)

Los pre-request scripts están escritos en JavaScript y funcionan de la misma manera que los scripts para pruebas, el proceso que puedes seguir es:

1. En el pre-request script haces la petición del token
2. Guardas el resultado en una variable de ambiente
3. Lees la [variable de ambiente](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/variables-and-environments/variables/) en tus encabezados con interpolación.

Aquí hay un ejemplo que encontré:

```js
    /// Datos de para tu petición de autenticación
    const echoPostRequest = {
      url: 'https://<my url>.auth0.com/oauth/token',
      method: 'POST',
      header: 'Content-Type:application/json',
      body: {
        mode: 'application/json',
        raw: JSON.stringify(
            {
                client_id:'<your client ID>',
                client_secret:'<your client secret>',
                audience:'<my audience>',
                grant_type:'client_credentials'
            })
      }
    };

    var getToken = true;

    /// Revisas si tienes ya un token y su fecha de expiración.
    if (!pm.environment.get('accessTokenExpiry') || 
        !pm.environment.get('currentAccessToken')) {
        console.log('Token or expiry date are missing')

    /// Revisas si el token esta expirado.
    } else if (pm.environment.get('accessTokenExpiry') <= (new Date()).getTime()) {
        console.log('Token is expired')
    } else {
        getToken = false;
        console.log('Token and expiry date are all good');
    }


    /// Si no tienes token o ya está expirado solicitas un nuevo token.
    if (getToken === true) {
        pm.sendRequest(echoPostRequest, function (err, res) {
        console.log(err ? err : res.json());
            if (err === null) {
                console.log('Saving the token and expiry date')
                var responseJson = res.json();

                /// Guardas el token en las variables de entorno
                pm.environment.set('currentAccessToken', responseJson.access_token)

                var expiryDate = new Date();
                expiryDate.setSeconds(expiryDate.getSeconds() + responseJson.expires_in);
                pm.environment.set('accessTokenExpiry', expiryDate.getTime());
            }
        });
    }
```

[Link del ejemplo](https://gist.github.com/bcnzer/073f0fc0b959928b0ca2b173230c0669)

Answer (score -1):

```
/// Datos de para tu petición de autenticación
const echoPostRequest = {
  url: 'https://<my url>.auth0.com/oauth/token',
  method: 'POST',
  header: 'Content-Type:application/json',
  body: {
    mode: 'application/json',
    raw: JSON.stringify(
        {
            client_id:'<your client ID>',
            client_secret:'<your client secret>',
            audience:'<my audience>',
            grant_type:'client_credentials'
        })
  }
};
```

Comment: Las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad porque no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Por favor, edita la respuesta para añadir una descripción de qué es lo que hace este código, dónde iría, y cómo resuelve el problema. Lee [answer] para más información.